# Code in subscribe block not executed in unit test angular 2

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have a service called X()

I have in its constructor

```
constructor(private http: ApiService) { }
```

where ApiService extends Http.

in my spec file, I have a test

```
x.xx(payload).subscribe(() => {
          alert("Hi");
        });
```

This alert is not executed, the test is in async mode.

If I change the constructor to

```
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
```

it works.

What have I tried?

1. use providers to replace ApiService with Http[not working]

   providers: [
             {provide: ApiService, useClass: Http},]

2.Manually change private variable[not working]

```
x['http']=Http
```

*******************Update ********************************************

https://github.com/astronaut1712/ng2-http-intercept/blob/master/src/intercept.http.service.ts this is the APIService

Comment: please recreate the issue on stackblitz. This will make it easier to help out

Comment: https://github.com/astronaut1712/ng2-http-intercept/blob/master/src/intercept.http.service.ts  this is the APIService